# System hanged and CPU high under kernel code wait_event() and wake_up()

Tags: linux, multithreading, kernel, wait

I have two kernel threads which run a() and b() respectively. a() is trying to wake up b() as follows.

```
a() {
    while(1) {
       while( atomic_read(status) != SET_SLEEP )
           msleep(10);

       atomic_set(status, SET_RUN);
       printk( "..." );
       wake_up( wq );
    }

b() {
    while(1) {
        atomic_set(status, SET_SLEEP);
        printk( "..." );
        wait_event( wq, atomic_read(status) != SET_SLEEP );
        printk( "..." );
    }
```

After running both for a long time, whole system will be hanged and CPU got high. No any panic message is printed. Is there anyone has idea?

Comment: How long does it run before the issue presents itself? Have you turned on any available debugging to try and narrow down the root cause?

Comment: About 10 minutes. I have no idea to turn on possible debugging. It is not crashed. Just hanged and cannot see anything. Now, I doubt that there is something in wait_event() and wake_up(), "spin_lock" which cause deadlock and busy waiting.

Comment: You can create debugging by spitting out certain values with their variable name. You can also add code to show things like # CPU threads, etc.

Comment: If I increase the number of thread b(), it may hang about 1 minute.

Comment: Hi Lizz, of course I did it. I even printed which thread is working on which # CPU with which status and etc... But I got nothing. I doubt they are hanged in wait_event() or wake_up().

Comment: More information: my kernel version is 3.2.0

Answer (score 0):

The more we want to solve, the less we get....

As Lizz mentioned, I added many printk to print some information for debugging. But I got nothing because 'printk' is the most responsible for the bug.

I did the following experiment and I found an unbelievable result.
Run 1 thread of a() and 1024 threads of b(). a() is waking up each b() in a while loop 
Modify printk as follows.

```
write_lock_bh( &pk_lock );
printk( "print some debugging message" );
write_unlock_bh( &pk_lock );
```

Run once with lock and run once without lock.
Without lock, it hangs.
With lock, it runs properly.

Originally, printk is for debugging. Now it seems to be the root cause.

Is there anyone has such experience?

Answer (score 0):

try put a lock on status, lock will flush the statue in CPU a's cache into main memory so that CPU b gets the latest update. Or maybe set status as volatile.

Comment: Thanks, I have modified my first post (with atomic_t). But with printk, it is still hanged.